# HTML/CSS unexpected empty field on top of page

Tags: html, css

I made a HTML document and css, in the body i have 2 div tag, 1.header and 2.cssmenu
and i put padding and margin to zero in body, but there is a free empty part before my first div(meaning header).what is the problem , here is my code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/farbod_chitsaz/SQYV7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css' />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1><center>Online Shopping</center></h1></div>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>خانه</span></a></li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>محصولات</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>  افزورن کالا افزودن کالا</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Menus</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>محصولات</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Location</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h1>` tag in your header has a default margin. To get rid of it add this rule:

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SQYV7/1/)**

By the way, the `<center>` tag was [deprecated like a decade or two ago](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). This rule would solve that issue and the margin issue:

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SQYV7/2/)**

Finally, to deal with padding, margins, borders, and many of the other discrepancies between browsers and operating systems you may want to Google "CSS reset".

Comment: Why? See documentation here for ["margin collapse"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Comment: awsome , it's ok now.